# value saved to persistent store when user clicks a button

Tags: blackberry

In my application There is a BasicEditField and a button,When user click on the button the string entered in the BasicEditfield stored into  persistent store.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to store EditField text when button clicked:

```
button.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            PersistentObject store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject( 0xa3a56927824234L );
            store.setContents(basicEditField.getText());
            store.commit();
        }
    });
```